# Difficult integral of exponential function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is there a closed-form solution for integrals of the form
$$
V(a,b,c) := \int_a^\infty \exp( - b \,  x^c) \, \mathrm{d}x \quad a,b,c > 0 .
$$

Only for the special case $c=1$ I can figure out $V(a,b,1) = \exp(-b a) / b$. I would guess that it holds something like $V(a,b,c) \approx \exp(-b a^c)$, but is there an exact formula?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a,b,c>0$, the following changes of variables do the trick:
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-bx^{c}}dx & =a\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-b\left(ax\right)^{c}}dx & \text{(} x & \rightarrow ax \text{)}\\
 & =a\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-a^{c}bx^{c}}dx\\
 & =\frac{a}{c}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-a^{c}bx}x^{\frac{c}{c-1}}dx & \text{(} x & \rightarrow x^{1/c} \text{)}\\
 & =\frac{a}{c}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-a^{c}bx}/x^{\frac{c-1}{c}}dx\\
 & =\frac{a}{c}E_n(a^{c}b) & \text{ where } n & ={\frac{c-1}{c}}.
\end{align*}

The exponential integral $E_n$ is [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Relation_with_other_functions).

Answer (score 1):

According to Section 3.381 in *Gradshteyn and Ryzhik: Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* the answer is
$$
V(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{c b^{1/c}} \Gamma(1/c, b a^c),
$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the upper incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, except for some special cases. Consider $\int \exp(-x^2)dx$ (as part of the normal distribution).